# what is bounded support of a function?

Tags: calculus

In a section on integral of my textbook "Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra, and Differential Forms: A Unified Approach, 5th edition",

> $f$ has bounded support (i.e., there exists $R$ such that $f(\mathbf x) = 0$ when $|\mathbf x|$ > $R$).

Is this sentence correct? I wonder $|\mathbf x| < R$ may be correct?

Comment: $|x|>R$ is correct. The support is contained in $\{|x| \leq R\}$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. It totaly makes sense. Thank you!